# rosrun python executable

Tags: ros, python, archlinux, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do you set which python executable rosrun uses? I am on Arch linux and I assume rosrun defaults to python 3 while trying to interpret python 2.7 source, which of course fails.

EDIT: The issue was in the package scripts. They used "#!/usr/bin/env python" which defaults to python3 on Archlinux. I changed it to "#!/usr/bin/python2".

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200664/rosrun-python-executable/) by [clauniel](https://answers.ros.org/users/20215/clauniel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2015-01-09

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On Arch, since `/usr/bin/python` points to Python 3, some steps need to be taken when using ROS:

- Force the use of Python 2 by providing Python 2 paths/executables to catkin/CMake (as explained [in the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Arch#User_configuration)),
- Patch shebang lines of Python scripts to ensure that Python 2 is used. All the ROS packages available in the AUR are fixed automatically thanks to a script available in [ros-build-tools](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ros-build-tools/):

> ```
> # Fix Python2/Python3 conflicts
> /usr/share/ros-build-tools/fix-python-scripts.sh -v 2 /path/to/src/dir
> ```

---

Originally posted by [bchr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4609/bchr/) with karma: 596 on 2015-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

or

```
gedit ~/[your_workspace]/devel/setup.bash
```

And check the Python path.

I once had a similar problem where the Anaconda python interpreter messed up with catkin_make and srvs.

---

Originally posted by [kokirits](https://answers.ros.org/users/21162/kokirits/) with karma: 290 on 2015-01-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [clauniel](https://answers.ros.org/users/20215/clauniel/) on 2015-01-09**:
Afaik, PYTHONPATH points to libraries, not the executable. Changing it did not make a difference, however you led me on the right track. Thanks!

**Comment by [kokirits](https://answers.ros.org/users/21162/kokirits/) on 2015-01-09**:
Glad I could help!